Error while importing useForm into a Nextjs app
So I want to create a form component that utilizes useForm hook from "react-hook-form. I have upgraded my Typescript version and React-hook-form version globally, I have also made an attempt to add the "use client" at the top level of the file in which useForm is been imported to but still cant use it in my component.
Error:
All imports in import declaration are unused.ts(6192)
Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'.ts(2305)
import useForm

add-form.tsx
"use client";

import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { z } from "zod";

const formSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().min(2).max(50),
});

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";

export default function CreateForm() {
  return <form></form>;
}

package.json
........
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  } "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

React-hook-version
 "react-hook-form": "^7.51.3",

I have tried other resources, but still not working what can I do in this case.

When you put your cursor in import { | } from  'react-hook-form' and press ctrl + space, do you get any suggestion to useForm. I think it might be that you need to restart VS Code
